# Any alternatives to Google Apps for your domain?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-workspace

I'm specifically interested in a webmail service, but I will appreciate suggestions to replace other components too.

Comment: You can add additional domains to your existing Google Apps account as a separate domain to enjoy the same Google email service as that for the primary domain. See [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2014/02/you-dont-need-a-google-apps-alternative-for-email-hosting.html). So if all you want is Gmail for your own domain, just add it as a separate domain. No need for a separate apps account or any alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zoho](http://www.zoho.com/) offer a pretty comprehensive range of products, most of which are free for a limited number of users/projects/whatever...

- Calendar
- Challenge
- Chat
- Creator
- CRM
- Discussions
- Docs
- Gadgets
- Invoice
- Mail
- Meeting
- Notebook
- Office for Microsoft Sharepoint
- People
- Planner
- Polls
- Projects
- Recruit
- Reports
- Sheet
- Show
- Viewer
- Wiki
- Writer

Even though the functionality overlaps, they integrate with Google Apps in some places, so you could have a hybrid solution.

Comment: I like but don't love Zoho. They seem to be rather over-extended, and they're substantially buggier than Google Docs. This said, they have a lot more features, and if you're OK working around their quirks, they can be a great solution.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft [officelive](http://www.officelive.com) has web pages, email, etc. for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo is still alive, at least as for webmail. [See this.](http://overview.mail.yahoo.com)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: <qoute>I'm specifically interested in a webmail service</quote>. How is suggesting a Webmail service not an answer ? I

Comment: But the title states "For your domain"

Answer (score 0):

[Zimbra](http://zimbra.com) is a good alternative. You can find people that propose to host Zimbra for you on [Zimbra Hosting Providers](http://www.zimbra.com/partners/zimbra_hosting.html).